# Is Ubuntu itself vulnerable to Log4shell?

Tags: security, vulnerability

We run different versions of Ubuntu OS (mostly ver 18 and 20), on MANY machines. My question; Is Ubuntu OS affected by the Log4shell vulnerability now reported in log4js? TIA

Comment: Do your users have the ability to install Notepad++ on your Ubuntu machines?

Comment: Unknown - why do you ask?

Comment: I understood the known vector was a Notepad++ installer (for Windows, I presume).

Comment: By 18 & 20 do you mean Ubuntu Core 18 & Ubuntu Core 20?   As Ubuntu has used the *year* format for *snap* only products since 2016 and they can be impacted by  different CVEs to 18.04 & 20.04 for example.  If you're worried about CVEs why not check using the check site?   (On 18 & 20 user apps are *confined* thus have far more limited access to the root file-system when contrasted with 18.04 & 20.04 for example - they are different systems)

Comment: Reference: https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-44228

Comment: @ZeissIkon Notepad++ is written in C++, not Java. See https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/22260/log4j-vulnerability/3

Comment: @ZeissIkon how on earth is Notepad++ installer a known vector?

Comment: @ZeissIkon This vulnerability is reported to be easy to exploit, hence the fuss about it. Although I'm not familiar with the details, exploits won't be limited to a single vector.

Comment: [Ubuntu Security Podcast #142](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/episode-142/) spends over 10 minutes discussing the ramifications of this vulnerability. Worth a listen.

Answer (score 40):

**Generally, No**. Only folks who have a specific java package installed might be vulnerable.

- The deb package (`apache-log4j2`) is not part of a stock Ubuntu install. Most vulnerable systems run either webservers or java applications (like Minecraft servers). If you didn't install a server application, then you're unlikely to be affected by this vulnerability.
- Most affected folks who installed the software using the deb package have already received a patch to close the vulnerability.
- [Ubuntu Security Podcast #142](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/episode-142/) discusses the CVE, and is definitely worth listening to! Thanks to the hard-working engineers on the Ubuntu Security Team, keeping our Ubuntu systems safe.
- If you installed log4j2 as part of webserver or java application using a Snap package, check with the author of that snap for a security upgrade.
- If you installed log4j2 as part of your webserver or java application some other way (Appimage, Flatpak, Pip, Brew, compiled, etc), then it's up to you to return to that source and find a patched version...or to read [the CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228) for manual mitigation settings.
- If you have installed a whole software stack or platform consisting of many interrelated applications, then it's possible that the vulnerable software might be embedded in that stack. Consult the source you got it from.

From https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-5192-1

> Releases
> Ubuntu 21.10 Ubuntu 21.04 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
>
> Packages
> apache-log4j2 - Apache Log4j - Logging Framework for Java

...and...

> Update instructions
> The problem can be corrected by updating your system to the following package versions:

---

Let's expand this a bit for deb package users:

**How to tell if you are affected**

Simply ask apt:

```
me@me:~$ apt list apache-log4j2
```

There are three possible results:

```
Listing... Done

me@me:~$      <-- No output at all. It's not installed.
                  You're not vulnerable.


apache-log4j2/focal,now 2.11.2-1 amd64  <-- It's available, but NOT installed.
                  You're not vulnerable.


apache-log4j2/focal,now 2.11.2-1 amd64 [installed] <-- It's installed
                  You MIGHT be vulnerable.
```

If you're not vulnerable, you can stop here.

**If you MIGHT be vulnerable**, the next thing to look at is the package version returned by that string.

```
Ubuntu 18.04
apache-log4j2/bionic,now 2.10.0-2 amd64 [installed]           Vulnerable
apache-log4j2/bionic,now 2.10.0-2ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]  NOT Vulnerable

Ubuntu 20.04
apache-log4j2/focal,now 2.11.2-1 amd64 [installed]            Vulnerable
apache-log4j2/focal,now 2.15.0-0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]    NOT Vulnerable

Ubuntu 21.04
apache-log4j2/hirsute,now 2.13.3-1 amd64 [installed]          Vulnerable
apache-log4j2/hirsute,now 2.15.0-0.21.04.1 amd64 [installed]  NOT Vulnerable

Ubuntu 21.10
apache-log4j2/impish,now 2.13.3-1 amd64 [installed]           Vulnerable
apache-log4j2/impish,now 2.15.0-0.21.10.1 amd64 [installed]   NOT Vulnerable
```

The versions that are NOT Vulnerable have already been patched by the Ubuntu Security Team. Most folks have already received the patched version via Unattended Upgrades.

- That's what Unattended Upgrades does! It installs security upgrades without bothering you.

**If your system is Vulnerable**, then simply `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to pull in the latest security upgrades.

**About Snaps**: It might be possible that an unpatched log4j2 dwells within some snap packages.

- We probably won't know about it. Snap software audits, if any, are done by community members. An audit is not required to release a snap package.
- The whole point of snap confinement is to prevent such vulnerabilities from threatening the entire system.
- If you find a vulnerable snap package, file a bug report with the author!
- Snapd checks for upgraded packages multiple times each day. If a vulnerable snap package gets patched, you'll have that patch within a few hours.

Comment: It's probably a good idea to mention user-installed software. Stuff like PPAs, software suites with their own installers, compiled from source, etc. Those are not a part of Ubuntu, but Ubuntu users may have installed something like that, and they _must_ check such installations.

Comment: Good point. Added a bullet to the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications embed log4j code into their own java files, and a simple filename or package scan will not find the embedded code.
US-CERT has released a very nice scanner which looks inside .jar/.war/.ear files to find vulnerable log4j code.  This scanner found two unrelated applications on our servers containing vulnerable log4j code.
The US-CERT scanner can be found at: https://github.com/CERTCC/CVE-2021-44228_scanner