# How to fix CVE-2021-44228 bug related with log4j

Tags: 20.04, bug-reporting

Is there a patch to fix this vulnerability in the core?
How could we fix this?

**Vulnerability description:**

Apache Log4j2 <=2.14.1 JNDI features used in configuration, log messages, and parameters do not protect against attacker controlled LDAP and other JNDI related endpoints. An attacker who can control log messages or log message parameters can execute arbitrary code loaded from LDAP servers when message lookup substitution is enabled. From log4j 2.15.0, this behavior has been disabled by default. In previous releases (>2.10) this behavior can be mitigated by setting system property “log4j2.formatMsgNoLookups” to “true” or it can be mitigated in prior releases (<2.10) by removing the JndiLookup class from the classpath (example: zip -q -d log4j-core-*.jar org/apache/logging/log4j/core/lookup/JndiLookup.class).

Comment: What do you mean "in the core"? [Ubuntu itself isn't vulnerable to log4j](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380998/is-ubuntu-itself-vulnerable-to-log4shell/)

Comment: I mean by updating repository or if we have to download sources to fix this..

Comment: I think you need to read the answer posted above...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Ubuntu itself vulnerable to Log4shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1380998/is-ubuntu-itself-vulnerable-to-log4shell) Or are you asking how to apply patches yourself? Or are you asking something different? Discovering whether or not a patch *exists* is trivial -- since you have the CVE number, Google will happily tell you. So your question seems unclear to me.